# Layout and its elements cannot be added to any activity

Tags: android, layout, dialog, custom-component

I develop support classes for my application in another project, and later, I add it to my app. I have made a class that shows a dialog, and works perfectly in its project, but when I add it to my app's project doesn't recognize the layout and its elements.

[image]

I'm sure all are added, but seem like any haven't reference in the R xml. Do you know any solution? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Clean your project and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `Reference/Library Project` in the `Build Path` of your `Running application` then only you can use elements and layouts of that `Reference/Library Project` into your `Running application`.

Hope it helps you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check if in your imports you are importing your.package.R instead of android.R, it is a common issue